# Wordpress tables missing

Tags: wordpress, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I just installed a LAMP server on a raspberry pi and tried to install Wordpress on it. I wrote on the Wordpress forums and so on but no help. I get these errors when Wordpress does a automatic check:
`wp_posts: Table 'wordpress.wp_posts' doesn't exist wp_comments: Table 'wordpress.wp_comments' doesn't exist wp links: Table 'wordpress.wp_links' doesn't exist wp_options: Table 'wordpress.wp_options' doesn't exist wp_postmeta: Table 'wordpress.wp_postmeta' doesn't exist`
All they said on Wordpress was to do a database repair but I don’t know how?

Comment: Do you have access to the database management? You could set up WordPress on your PC, export the database and import it on your RPi.

Repairing the database can also be done like that: https://wpmudev.com/blog/repairing-corrupted-broken-missing-files-databases-wordpress/

Comment: How do I set it up on my PC, do I just do it on Wordpress website or like download an app of it or do I have to delete the pc and make it into a lamp server like with the raspberry pi @IWOS

Comment: You can do this with a software like MAMP. There you can start a server on your PC, install WordPress there, including a database and configure everything. Then when the installation works, you can import it to you RPi